# Postgresql query between two unix timestamp

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table called **clients** below are attached image

[image]

I want to select all clients whose age between 21 yr to 35 yr, where the dob are stored like so "1403830861".

I am trying below query but no result.

```
select * 
from clients 
where to_timestamp(dob/1000) > timestamp '2014-01-15 00:00:00' 
  and to_timestamp(dob/1000) < timestamp '2016-01-15 23:59:59';
```

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: And why are you storing the birth date as a number? You should store that as a proper `DATE`

Comment: Postgres has a `between` command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root cause is this:

```
to_timestamp(dob/1000) >  timestamp '2014-01-15 00:00:00'
```

Anyone born **after** 2014-01-15 would only be 2 years today (December 2016).

So unless you have 2 year old people in your database, that condition won't return anything.

The shortest way to write this, is to use the `age()` function:

```
select *
from clients
where extract(year from age(to_timestamp(dob::bigint/1000))) between 21 and 35;
```

That will *include* people with age 21 or 35

---

If you store the DOB as a date string (and not a number string), you obviously don't need the `to_timestamp()` but `to_date()` to convert the string into a proper date:

```
select *
from clients
where extract(year from age(to_date(dob, 'DD-MM-YYYY'::date))) between 21 and 35;
```

I assumed your DOB values are stored in the format `'DD-MM-YYYY'` if you are using a different format, adjust the `to_date()` call.

---

Unrelated, but: it would be **much** better to store the date of birth as a `date`  column rather then a number.

And you should ***NEVER*** store numbers in `varchar` columns.

Comment: Running mentioned query gives error

`ERROR:  operator does not exist: character varying / integer
LINE 3: where extract(year from age(to_timestamp(dob/1000))) between...
                                                    ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.`

Comment: @gagan: I overlooked that your definition of `dob` is even worse then I thought. You need to cast the string to a proper number  - see my edit. Bu why on earth are you storing numbers in a `varchar`? Storing a `date` as a number is already a bad design choice, but storing a number in a varchar is even worse

Comment: I understand but problem this app is very old and don't want to take risk at this moment of time. 

Now  another error

SQL error:

`ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "04-05-1991"`

Comment: @Gagan: then apparently you are **not** storing the DOB as a number but as a proper date. Or you are actually storing some values as dates and some as number - **exactly** the reason why you shouldn't store data like that in a `varchar`

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM clients
WHERE dob BETWEEN
  EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM date '2014-01-15 00:00:00') AND
  EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM date '2016-01-15 23:59:59');
```

Comment: You might want to explain the advantage of this query: that it _can_ use an index on `dob` - however it would still not return people with an age between 21 and 45

Answer (score 0):

You can use next SQL construction

```
WHERE my_date_field 
    between to_timestamp({period_from}) and to_timestamp({period_to})
```

or ugly

```
WHERE my_date_field 
    BETWEEN 
(TIMESTAMP 'epoch' + 1605964659 * INTERVAL '1 second')
          AND
(TIMESTAMP 'epoch' + 1608556659 * INTERVAL '1 second')
```

Comment: `(TIMESTAMP 'epoch' + 1605964659 * INTERVAL '1 second')` can be simplified to `to_timestamp(1605964659)`